# vector tiles and textpath

Tags: leaflet, openlayers-3, vector-tiles

I am using TileStache to render a vector tile layer, works nicely in OpenLayers 3.

http://standup.csc.kth.se/maps/projects.html

However, I would like to add "text path" along the roads (e.g. show the year of expected completion). I could not find any way to do textpath in OpenLayers 3. I only found one for OpenLayers2...

I looked at Leaflet for the this purpose but... it does not work with vector tiles, except with plugins that don't seem to allow a combination with the Leaflet textpath plugin...

Is there any solution for doing textpath with vector tiles ?

Comment: So you want an OpenLayers solution, right? If yes, the `leaflet` tag can be removed, so the leaflet guys don't need to bother.

Answer (score 1):

Text paths along lines are not yet supported in OpenLayers 3, but are a planned feature that should be available later this year.

In the meantime, you could calculate label points and angles on the server and add those to your vector tiles. Then you can style them with a simple `ol.style.Text` and the `rotation` option.

Comment: Thanks, that would indeed be a way forward for me as I only want to show 4-digit years, so the fact that different parts of the curve have different angles is not a  big problem. Do you have a hint for how to choose regular points  (and how to compute their way angle) using postgis?